# iOS MessageKit didTapAccessoryView not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I am using MessageKit to implement the Chat UI for my App. I have added an icon in AccessoryView using configureAccessoryView method. Also, I implemented didTapAccessoryView from MessageCellDelegate. But the method is not getting called while didTapMessage is getting called perfectly.

Here is my code snippets for MessageCellDelegate

```
extension MessagingController: MessageCellDelegate {
    func didTapAccessoryView(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("didTapAccessoryView view tapped")
    }
    
    func didTapMessage(in cell: MessageCollectionViewCell) {
        print("didTapMessage view tapped")
    }
}
```

Here is my code for collectionView setup

```
messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
        messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
```

Comment: Code snippet for added view?

Comment: Check this snippet. https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/main/Example/Sources/View%20Controllers/AdvancedExampleViewController.swift

Comment: The added view should have `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` to respond to accessoryView tap through `MessageCellDelegate`. Let me know the result.